# How to fetch data and display using "GET"-with Authorization header using Rest API

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, http-get

I am having one url to get data and to display. Here I need to follow some steps for authAuthorization header: to base64,sha256  0r sha512

So here I coded to get data with Authorization header.But in my console I got error:

```
str: {
  "error_code": "invalid_auth_header",
  "message": "Invalid authorization. Use an auth header or access hash"
}
```

I am new to HTTP/GET, Authorization header and all. What am I doing wrong and what do I need to change there to work that out?

Here is my code (This is the update code based on the below answer):

```
 #import "ViewController.h"
 #import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>

 @interface ViewController ()

 @end

 @implementation ViewController

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      NSString *userName = @"testingyouonit@gmail.com";
      NSString *password = @"testingyouonit2";

      NSData *plainData = [password dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      NSString *base64String = [plainData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
      base64String=[self sha256HashFor: base64String];

      //setting the string of the url taking from appliance IP.
      NSString *urlString = @"https://api.exampleURL.com/files";

      NSMutableURLRequest *request= [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
      [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
      [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

      NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", userName, base64String];
      NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64Encoding]];
      [request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

      NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

      NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

      NSLog(@"str: %@", str);
}
-(NSString*)sha256HashFor:(NSString*)input {
     const char* str = [input UTF8String];
     unsigned char result[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
     CC_SHA256(str, strlen(str), result);

     NSMutableString *ret = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH*2];
     for(int i = 0; i<CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
          [ret appendFormat:@"%02x",result[i]];
     }
     return ret;
}
```

Comment: @jace my question is related with your post

Comment: I think the problem is you are putting a URL in the header value, try put the password you generated, so the header code should look like: `[request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", base64String] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];`

Comment: yes i have change , but still me getting that error i mentioned above

Comment: for an information - does i did all encoding base64 &  SHA256 hash correct on my code or wrong

Comment: They look fine to me, between, you can test it by pasting your URL in a browser or using an API client like PostMan and check the result if it's working with the generated password (you can print the generated password in console).

Comment: Also, change this line `base64String=[self sha256HashFor: password];` to `base64String=[self sha256HashFor: base64String];`, you are not using the base64 encrypted string at all.

Comment: in console i did encode and decode my password.its working fine only.but dont know why no data are showing in my console

Comment: that also i change dude ,but same problem.....hitting  my head lot this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, please fix the following error in your code:

1. Change the `base64String=[self sha256HashFor: password];` to `base64String=[self sha256HashFor: base64String];`.
2. `NSString *str1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.exampleurl/user/data",userName,base64String];` to `NSString *str1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.exampleurl/user/data"];`

After that, to use a basic authorization use the following code:

```
NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", userName, base64String];
NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64Encoding]];
[request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

Comment: the last four line code with replacement of what .i.e i am new to this.where i have to add that line

Comment: They should replace the following code `[request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@",str1] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];`

Comment: Awesome dude, uhhh thanks a lot.Kindly check my updated post whether is correct of your code

Comment: one more question. if i need to display that data in my collection view as grid means how to do that with grid view

Comment: This is out of the question scope, you could search for parsing JSON to `NSDictionary` and how to use `UICollectionView` for more details of how to use it. There is a lot of tutorial out there :)

Comment: ok .but from my code verse NSURLDelegate method are how different.           `1.Connection did receive response                                                                      2.Connection did receive data                                                                               3.connection didFailWithError                                                                             4.connectionDidFinishLoading `                                                                         Should i use in my code.i dont't know about this .